# How to make ion-select select-icon position right but just icon, select-text position left

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I want it to have a standart design on ionic input elements. I have an ion-select element and this element inside select box text align-left but I want select-icon align right. I do on HTML element like that: https://ibb.co/99YXc8B. But I am not doing in the sccs style. I try a lot. Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fdqf4z?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss

Answer (score 1):

Replace your CSS with this CSS code.it will works.

```
     [inline-icon] {
        font-size: 2em !important;
        padding-right: 3px !important;
        color: #808080ba !important;
    }
    .try{
      color: red;
      width:100%;
    }
    ion-select
    {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```